# Long Term Fraction Spent Sitting In Left Seat

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus

In a cafe I frequent, the area where I sit has a left seat and a right seat, and I enjoy switching where I sit. If I'm in the left seat and I feel like switching, there's a 50% chance that I'll move to the right seat. Similarly, if I'm in the right seat and I feel like switching, there's a 70% chance that I'll switch to the left seat. After much time has gone by, what fraction of time will I have spent sitting in the left seat?

I tried to solve this problem by first letting L be the fraction of time I spent sitting in the left seat, and R be the fraction of time I spent sitting in the right seat. I noticed that $L+R=1$. Then, I let $$L' = 0.5L + 0.5R$$ where  L' represents the fraction of time you spend in the left seat in the next iteration. Since $L'=L$ in the long run, the equation becomes $$L = 0.5L + 0.5R$$ I substituted $L+R=1$ in to get:
$$L=0.5L+0.5(1-L)$$
$$L=0.5L+0.5-0.5L$$
$$L=0.5$$
Therefore, the fraction of time sitting in the left seat in the long run is 50%.
Is this the correct way to approach this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure the problem is clear.  Are you switching seats *constantly*?  Every hour?  Every minute?  Do you ever leave this cafe?   Nor is your solution clear...where did you use the assumptions about the switching probabilities?

Comment: I think the cafe bit just adds confusion (as one typically doesn't switch seats hundreds of times while in a cafe).  Why not rephrase the problem without any of that stuff?

Comment: As another thought...this is very easy to simulate.  Why not do that?  That will at least tell you the answer, which is always helpful.

Comment: Frankly, no idea about the specifics of the problem. However, I believe that fundamentally, it is a problem related to the steady state behavior of a markov chain.

Comment: Ok, so phrase it that way.  As I say, the current phrasing doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Could you give me some suggestions to phrase the problem better?

Comment: "Describe the steady state of a Markov process with two active states, $A,B$, and transition probabilities $.5, .7$ between them."

Comment: $L'=0.5L+0.7R$ not $L'=0.5L+0.5R$ since there is a $70$ percent chance of switching when n the right seat compared to a $50$ percent chance for a left seat. So we have $L=0.5L+0.7R=0.5L+0.7(1-L)=-0.2L+0.7$ so $1.2L=0.7$ so $L=7/12$